¿Cómo puedo guardar los datos de un Jframende Java cuando me muevo a otro?
Lo que sucede es que tengo un Jframe Pacientes donde me muestra un arreglo de datos que es ingresado por el usuario, pero al momento de moverme a otro Jframe y volver a este los datos no permanecen y es como si nunca se hubiera digitado algun dato

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
